# laravel httpd document root doesn't change

Tags: laravel, apache, httpd.conf, document-root

it's my first time to use laravel and config apache and I've a problem with apache document root, it doesn't change.
It always show apache homepage
I'm using a vm with virtualbox, and my conf.d file finish with this lines:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/laravel/public"

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName 192.168.56.3
    #ServiceAlias www.test.laravel.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel/public
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/var/www/laravel/public">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        ReWriteEngine On
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</Directory>
```

Do you know what is wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Have you restarted the apache? (and checked the config is valid), whats your host OS? Are you sure you are connecting to the VM and not lets say stock MacOS server?

Comment: Looks like RewriteRule is necessary

Comment: The syntax check retunr this:
||
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using localhost.localdomain. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK
||
The rewrireRule is in <Directory  ...
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

It's ok?

Comment: Try removing RewriteRule line.

Comment: Done, but nothing is changed

Comment: It seems you changed Rewrite Rule and made a mistake - I think it should be like this: `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]` (since you are already in context of `public` directory).
Possibly check that file too: "/var/www/laravel/public/public/.htaccess" (note 2 times `public` in path)

Comment: I've tried to change only the DocumentRoot line to  DocumentRoot "/var/www/laravel/public"   without add vitualhost and directory and it works! But aache doesn't execute php...   this is another problem